# How to add script if pointer not moving it will perform action

Tags: python

I'm having trouble finding the best code/script to add in my code. If the pointer wont move it will perform a right click. Since my gesture is performing nly Left Click, I want to create a logic that it mouse not move it will perform left click after 1 sec ot any time.

My code or my Left Click:

```
elif(len(conts)==1):
    x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
    if(pinchFlag==0):
        if(abs((w*h-openw*openh)*100/(w*h))<=360):

            pinchFlag=1
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            openx,openy,openw,openh=(0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: Complete code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413672/add-right-click-on-virtual-mouse-using-gesture-python-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Right Click to virtual mouse using gesture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413672/how-to-add-right-click-to-virtual-mouse-using-gesture)